# Is DPAPI still valid option to protect eg. encryption key?

Tags: encryption, java, windows-dpapi

I have an Java client program for Windows having a properties file that I need to be able to encrypt (protect it if a malicious user accesses the server and properties file) but the client program of course needs to be able to read it (even when server offline). I am considering the DPAPI to encrypt the secret key, or why not the whole properties...

I'm thinking of using eg. [JDPAPI](https://jdpapi.sourceforge.net/) or [jKeyring](https://github.com/joval/jKeyring) but am wondering if the whole DPAPI still is valid solution considering it is so old? Of course I understand that it's only API and the 'engine' behind can change and update but just want to make sure.

Also the JDPAPI is old lib, and jKeyring is the closest I can find to 'fresh' but if you know some good lib, I would be glad to take a look.

And of course, if there are some solutions more elegant with better security, I am willing to consider them also.

Comment: In your threat example, who is the malicious user logging in as, and what privileges do you expect them to be able to attain?

Comment: Probably an user having access to the server and properties file, not necessarily admin user. Currently the encryption key can be derived from obfuscated Java code and I would like to improve this.

Comment: If the malicious actor has admin access, there's nothing you can do. Assuming they're not admin, is it reasonable to assume that the service (the one decrypting the data) would be running under a different user account (e.g. `NETWORK SERVICE`) than the malicious user, and that the malicious user could not impersonate that user? If so, is there a reason that you couldn't just restrict the ACL on the config file to only allow the service and administrators to read it?

Comment: Yes, the program would run under it's own account (AD). Is it truly so that server admin can impersonate user 'xyz' and would be able get the value decrypted though DPAPI? Even though AD account?

Comment: An administrator can access all DPAPI contents. Even if they couldn't through usermode, they could just load a kernelmode driver.

Comment: Maybe a combination of DPAPI and ACL to restrict the read privilege to admins and 'xyz'. Do you consider DPAPI still valid API for encrypting? Better than hardcoded encryption key in Java? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question of whether to use DPAPI vs. other encryption methods is not necessarily material to your actual goal, which is to prevent an attacker who compromises the system from reading sensitive information in a configuration file.

The first thing you need to figure out is your threat model.

It is important to understand that an attacker whose sphere of control encompasses the defender's sphere of control will always be able to gain access to the defender's resources:

[image: Venn diagram showing a defender's sphere of control being fully encompassed by an attacker's sphere of control]

Consequently, it is *not possible* to secure resources against a threat actor who has a greater or equal amount of control than the user being targeted. For example, an attacker with access to an administrator account or with physical access to the system can *always* gain access to every resource on that system, because their sphere of influence encompasses the entire system. If a defender is also an administrator, both the attacker and defender have an equal sphere of influence. In either case, no resources can be secured against the attacker.

A corollary to this is that an attacker whose sphere of control intersects with the defender's sphere of control will have access to some but not all of the defender's resources:

[image: Venn diagram showing an attacker's sphere of control intersecting with a defender's sphere of control, with unprotected resources in the intersection.]

This Venn diagram might represent two low-privilege users - they cannot read files in each others' user profile directories, but they can access shared resources. The lines formed at each side of the intersection are security boundaries.

With that in mind, let's build a threat model for your scenario.

The resource you are trying to protect is a file on a Windows operating system. What capabilities and privileges does your attacker have in relation to this resource? Let's consider the following threat actors:

1. An unauthenticated attacker on the network.
2. An attacker authenticated as the user account that normally accesses the configuration file.
3. An attacker authenticated as a low privilege (non-admin) user account, but not the user account that normally accesses the configuration file.
4. An authenticated attacker who compromises a restricted service account (e.g. a process running as NETWORK SERVICE) on the target system.
5. An authenticated attacker with access to a high privilege (admin) user on the target system.
6. An unauthenticated attacker with access to the system's storage device in an offline context (e.g. physical theft of the disk). Note that this is different from an attacker with unrestricted physical access to the device, which is out of scope for this threat model.

Given these descriptions of threat actors, you can identify their *spheres of control*, i.e. the set of resources that the threat actors have agency over:

1. An unauthenticated attacker on the network has no immediate control over resources on the system (unless they are publicly shared, which we will assume is not the case for this threat model).
2. An attacker who is authenticated as the user that normally accesses the configuration file is *inherently* capable of reading the contents of the file. An attacker in this position has the exact same sphere of control as a legitimate user, and therefore has access to all of the same resources. Even if interactive access is required in order to gain access to the sensitive information in the configuration file (e.g. by protecting the file with a password) the attacker can simply wait until the legitimate user decrypts the configuration file. Even if you delegate the decryption process to a higher privileged service (e.g. with DPAPI) the decrypted configuration data still ends up in the hands of the user, at which point the attacker can access it to. It is not possible to secure the configuration file against this threat.
3. An attacker authenticated as a low-privilege user other than the one that normally accesses the file is prevented from accessing other users' files by the operating system's access controls. If the configuration file is placed within the user's profile directory (e.g. in `%APPDATA%`) then the file will be protected with a DACL that only allows access by that user, the Administrators group, and the built-in `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` account. The DACL security boundary protects the configuration file against this particular threat actor. An attacker authenticated as a low-privilege user would need to elevate their privileges (either vertically, or horizontally to the user that owns the configuration file) in order to gain access to the configuration file; at that point they would become one of the other threat actors mentioned in this threat model.
4. An attacker with control over a service running as a restricted service account (e.g. `LOCAL SERVICE` or `NETWORK SERVICE`) has very limited access to resources on the system. The DACLs applied to user profile directories do not include these service accounts, so files stored within the user profile directory cannot be accessed by these service accounts. Furthermore, these restricted service accounts do not have the ability to impersonate users without credentials. As such, the DACL is a security boundary that protects the configuration file against this particular threat actor.
5. An attacker who has control over an administrative user account (or another high privilege account like `SYSTEM`) has complete control over the system. They may take ownership of any securable resource, they can read and modify the memory of any process, and they may install kernel-mode drivers to arbitrarily modify the behaviour of the operating system. Securing any local resource against an attacker with these privileges is an intractable problem.
6. An unauthenticated attacker with access to the system's storage device in an offline context may read the contents of the disk. If the disk is unprotected, the attacker may read any files that they want. If the disk is protected with full-disk encryption (FDE) such as BitLocker, the attacker cannot read the contents of the disk without knowing the password. If BitLocker is used with a TPM in unattended mode (i.e. without a password) then the attacker will not be able to read the contents of the hard disk in an offline context.

Given this threat model, we can summarise the threats and suitable controls:

| Level of access | Effective controls | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Unauthenticated | N/A | This threat actor has no access to resources on the system. No controls need to be utilised. |
| Application user | None | Same sphere of control as the legitimate user; resource cannot be secured. |
| Low-privilege user | DACL | A low privilege user cannot access files owned by another user. |
| Service account | DACL | A restricted service account cannot (by default) access files owned by a normal user. |
| Admin/SYSTEM | None | Sphere of control encompasses the legitimate user and entire system; resource cannot be secured. |
| Offline storage | BitLocker | DACLs are not an effective control if an attacker can read the disk directly; this is mitigated by encrypting data at rest. |

Each of these threats, with the exception of the two intractable ones, can be mitigated by built-in filesystem access controls and BitLocker.

In the case of protecting offline storage, encrypting *only* the configuration file but not using BitLocker (or other FDE) is a weak security control. In the case of DPAPI, an attacker could dump the SAM from the disk and crack the NTLM hashes to gain access to the user's password, then use that to decrypt the file. Furthermore, if an attacker can access the disk surreptitiously, they might modify files on the disk (e.g. adding a malicious executable and SYSTEM service entry) to gain admin access.

Performing additional encryption at rest in the application does not provide additional security. If you consider the spheres of control in each threat scenario, you can see why: in the intractable cases (same sphere of control or greater sphere of control) the attacker has access to all the same resources that the legitimate user does, so they are inherently able to access the decryption key and/or the decrypted configuration file; in the other threat scenarios the file is *already* protected by access controls or full disk encryption.

This isn't to say that there *aren't* reasons why you might want to encrypt the file in addition to using FDE. One example would be to provide protection against the file contents being leaked, for example if an unencrypted backup is compromised or if an attacker finds and exploits a directory traversal attack to download the config file.

A suitable security control for mitigating this threat must ensure that the keys used to decrypt the file are outside the sphere of control of the attacker. If you encrypt the file using a hard-coded key in your application or a key stored in a file, the key itself is just as accessible as the configuration file, rendering the encryption pointless. The usual analogy here is installing a padlock and leaving the key right next to it.

If the key used to encrypt the file is instead provided interactively and is only stored in memory, then an attacker who is limited to reading files on disk would be unable to read the sensitive information from the configuration file. In this scenario, the keyboard strokes from the user entering the password and the derived key plus decrypted configuration data stored in process memory are resources outside of the attacker's control.

DPAPI is a fairly good option for mitigating the file leak scenario because it takes care of the encryption and key unlock/derivation for you. If the encrypted configuration file is leaked to an attacker with no other access to the system, they will be unable to decrypt it. If the data encrypted with DPAPI is associated with a user rather than the machine (i.e. `CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE` is not passed `CryptProtectData`) then this security control remains effective even if the threat actor has access to the encrypted file and to a non-admin account other than the one that encrypted the data (scenarios 3 and 4). However, DPAPI is *not* effective against an attacker who has access to the encrypted file and to an administrative user account or the user account that encrypted the data (scenarios 2 and 4). In scenario 2, the application can simply call `CryptUnprotectData` on the blob to decrypt it. In scenario 4, the attacker can wait until the user logs on interactively (thus unlocking their DPAPI keys) and then use their administrative access to impersonate that user to unprotect the data, or take over one of the user's processes to do the same, or load a tool like Mimikatz to dump the DPAPI keys from the LSA.

In summary, placing the config file in the user's profile directory (e.g. in `%APPDATA%`) protects it from being accessed by non-admin users and restricted service accounts, because the default DACL that is applied disallows access from those accounts. BitLocker is an effective security control for protecting the data at rest. An attacker with admin access, or with access to the user account that uses the client software whose configuration file you're trying to protect, will always be able to gain access to the plaintext contents of the configuration file. Additional at-rest encryption with DPAPI is only useful for protecting against leakage of the key file and will not provide any additional security in cases where an attacker has interactive access.

Comment: This is awesome! You just educated me more than 5 years in business. As I read your scenarios, I think the 'leakage' and non-admin users are just the things I want to protect the properties against. I have no control over the physical server, nor the admin users so I cannot make an impact there - in this case I think I will continue investigating the DPAPI along with making sure that ACL settings are as strict as they can be.